# Bing Maps V8 JS API GroundOverlay beneathLabels mouse events

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, bing-api

I use a transparent png as groundoverlay covering the whole map.I must set beneathLabels=false because the label-layer of the map makes some parts of my overlay unreadable. But with beneathLabels=false all the mouse/keyboard events goes to my groundoverlay not to the map anymore. I know thi sis documented but I don't want that, how can I route that events to the map? In the google-api I simple declare the groundoverlay as non-clickable. Or ist there any other way than groundoverly to put a transparent png above the whole map without capturing also all events ?

Comment: drawOrder is also not working. No matter if my custom overlay have drawOrder=100 or drawOrder -100 it is always beneath the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe to get the mouse events to go through the ground overlay the `pointer-events` CSS style needs to be set to `none`. I believe this isn't supported for images in IE10 (min supported browser by Bing Maps when this SDK was released, so likely why this isn't a built-in option). Doing some experimenting, the following seems to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script>
    var map, overlay;

    function GetMap() {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
            center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-16.366, -46.8945),
            zoom: 17
        });

        overlay = new Microsoft.Maps.GroundOverlay({
            bounds: Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromEdges(-16.36523189120857, -46.89686679103114, -16.3674247514764, -46.89337059621697),
            imageUrl: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Foto_a%C3%A9rea_de_Una%C3%AD_detalhando_o_c%C3%B3rrego_Canabrava_3.jpg',
            rotation: 298,          
            beneathLabels: false
        });
        map.layers.insert(overlay);
        
        //Access the underlying image object and disable pointer events so that mouse events flow through to the map.
        overlay._img.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=[Your Bing Maps Key]"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:800px;height:600px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great rbrundritt, that works for my case !